# My own print screen key

Tags: c, printscreen

How can we make a program to substitute the "print screen" key for the same function(i-e to get the picture of the whole screen ) with some other kry, in C language.

Comment: 1) which OS / what GUI / which desktop environment? 2) do you want another key working like printscreen normally does, or do you want printscreen key doing something else that it normally does?

Comment: I want to make a new default key for print screen and I am using windows 8.

Answer (score -3):

```
void dump_buffer()
{
   IDirect3DSurface9* pRenderTarget=NULL;
   IDirect3DSurface9* pDestTarget=NULL;
     const char file[] = "Pickture.bmp";
   // sanity checks.
   if (Device == NULL)
      return;

   // get the render target surface.
   HRESULT hr = Device->GetRenderTarget(0, &pRenderTarget);
   // get the current adapter display mode.
   //hr = pDirect3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,&d3ddisplaymode);

   // create a destination surface.
   hr = Device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(DisplayMde.Width,
                         DisplayMde.Height,
                         DisplayMde.Format,
                         D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,
                         &pDestTarget,
                         NULL);
   //copy the render target to the destination surface.
   hr = Device->GetRenderTargetData(pRenderTarget, pDestTarget);
   //save its contents to a bitmap file.
   hr = D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(file,
                              D3DXIFF_BMP,
                              pDestTarget,
                              NULL,
                              NULL);

   // clean up.
   pRenderTarget->Release();
   pDestTarget->Release();
}
```

their you go

Comment: Please offer a little more context rather than dumping an entire code block as an answer